# Squid basic auth connection problems

Tags: proxy, authentication, squid, connection, timeout

We are using squid proxy with basic authentication. Each user has it's own outgoing ip configured. See parts of our squid.conf:

```
# Authentication Basic Auth
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords
auth_param basic realm proxy
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow authenticated
http_access deny all

acl u0001 proxy_auth u0001
acl u0002 proxy_auth u0002
acl u0003 proxy_auth u0003
acl u0004 proxy_auth u0004

http_access allow u0001
http_access allow u0002
http_access allow u0003
http_access allow u0004

tcp_outgoing_address 2a03:f80:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX u0001
tcp_outgoing_address 2a03:f80:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX u0002
tcp_outgoing_address 2a03:f80:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX u0003
tcp_outgoing_address 2a03:f80:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX u0004
```

Sometimes, when we connect our service to an authenticated user, the connection just hangs and terminates after 30 seconds. The behavior is not reproducible and we cannot see anything in the cache.log or access.log.

Has anyone encountered similar behavior or any hint for a solution?

Happy to provide more information on request.

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Problem is (almost) solved. It seems not to be on our side, though. :(

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/8334